# Creating & connecting to a Azure Stage without SAS token

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been working on this all day yesterday and I've read countless posts.

Here is the post I've read:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html#option-2-generating-a-sas-token

https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/configuring-azure-active-directory-as-an-identity-provider

We had some consultants that came in an connected to the Azure BLOB, I currently see a 3 stages connected and when I do a LIST @ I get the correct result.

However, If I create a new stage and I do  LIST@ , I get the following error:

**Failure using stage area. Cause: [The specified resource does not exist. (Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFound; More info: The required credentials may be missing or invalid.)]**

I've gone to portal.azure and copied the key from ACCESS KEY.  Still get the same error.  When I click on SAS ( Shared access signature ) at the bottom of the page, the key is grayed out.

I know the container is accessible via the previously created stages. It's just when i create a new stage in a new database, I get the above error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by doing a clone of the stage.  By doing the clone of stage, you don't need to re-enter the encryption key.